# Cannot see git log, history on the Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I install gerrit on my linux comupter.
All of the git commands operate very well.
However, after pushing the commit, there is no logs on the gerrit.
I can see the log with "git log on the shell",
however, I could not see the logs on the web page.

I use the PostgreSql and ~/gerrit/git/ folder looks normal.

What should I do to see the code history on the web?

Comment: go to the "git web" to check the log.

Comment: Are you pushing to gerrit or are you pushing directly to your git folder and thus by-passing gerrit?

Answer (score 2):

The only commits you'll ever see in the Gerrit web interface are commits that have been (or are about to be) reviewed, i.e. commits at some point pushed to refs/for/some-branch-name. Commits pushed to refs/heads/some-branch-name (either via Gerrit or straight into the file system) will not be visible in Gerrit. You'll have to use a repository viewer like [cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/) or [Gitiles](https://code.google.com/p/gitiles/) for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are directly pushing to git using command "**git push origin master (or some branch)**". In this case, changes will go directly to git repo, and will update your git log. But if you want that particular change to go through proper review system or through gerrit, you need to push it to refs using the below command:
   "**git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch name**"

By using above command, it will go to gerrit and you will be able to see the change in gerrit UI also. And one more thing, since you have pushed it from your local repo, it will also present in your git log of that local repo , so don't get confused ;). Check in some other repo, you will get the difference.